# A question about Artin's proof of the spectral theorem.

Tags: linear-algebra

On pg. 253, Artin's Algebra says the following:

> Let $T$ be a Hermitian operator on a Hermitian vector space $V$. There is an orthonormal basis of $V$ consisting of eigenvectors of $T$.

While proving this, Artin says that the matrix of $T$ has $a_{11}=a$, where $a$ is the eigenvalue of an eigenvector of $T$, and $a_{n1}=0$ for $n>1$.

I don't understand why this is.

Comment: He probably said that V has a basis such that the matrix of T with respect to that basis has that form.  This is because T has an eigenvector.  Take the first element of the basis to be that eigenvector.

Comment: You should at least mention the edition of the book that you are using. My page 253 definitely does not say this. And I think you need some context.

Comment: [Related question, asked 3 hours apart](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/899215/a-question-regarding-artins-proof-of-the-spectral-theorem/)

Answer (score 0):

The matrix of $T$ with respect to an ordered basis $\beta = (v_1,\ldots, v_N)$ is
the matrix whose $i$th column is $[T(v_i)]_\beta$, the coordinate vector of $T(v_i)$ with respect to the basis $\beta$.  In other words,
\begin{equation}
[T]_\beta = \begin{bmatrix} [T(v_1)]_\beta \cdots [T(v_N)]_\beta \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation}

If $v_1$ is an eigenvector of $T$ with eigenvalue $a$, then
\begin{align*}
T(v_1) &= a v_1 \\&= a v_1 + 0 \cdot v_2 + \cdots + 0 \cdot v_N.
\end{align*}
This shows that the coordinate vector of $T(v_1)$ with respect to the basis $\beta$ is
\begin{equation*}
[T(v_1)]_\beta = \begin{bmatrix} a \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}.
\end{equation*}
So the first column of $[T]_\beta$ is all zeros, except for the first component which is equal to $a$.