# A question regarding Artin's proof of the Spectral Theorem.

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a question regarding Artin's proof of the Spectral Theorem as given in his textbook "Algebra". On my edition, it is on pg. 254, although it might be different for others. 
The statement is

> Let $T$ be a Hermitian operator on a Hermitian vector space $V$. There is an orthonormal basis of $V$ consisting of eigenvectors of $T$.

I have inserted a screenshot of the proof below.

[image]

1. When we move on to the matrix $N$, and choose an eigenvector, how can we be sure that this eigenvector is orthogonal to the previously chosen eigenvector?
2. What is the point of "extending to an orthonormal basis"? I don't see it being used anywhere in the proof.

Thanks.

Comment: [Related question, asked 3 hours apart](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/899100/a-question-about-artins-proof-of-the-spectral-theorem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The funny thing is, your second question is answered by the first. When you extend to an orthonormal basis from $v_1$, you are ensuring that any eigenvector of $N$ (with a $0$ appended to the beginning) is orthogonal to $v_1$.

---

Edit: Choose eigenvector $v_1$, and use the Gram-Schmidt process to extend to an orthonormal basis. Then the matrix $M$ with respect to this basis will be upper-triangular (hence the zeros in the first column). Because it is Hermitian, the first row will also be filled with zeros, and also $N$ will also be Hermitian. So you know not only that
$$T(c_1 v_1 + \cdots + c_n v_n)=ac_1v_1 + T(c_2 v_2 + \cdots c_n v_n)$$
(because of the zeros in the first row)
but also that $T(c_2 v_2 + \cdots c_n v_n)$ is a linear combination of the $v_2, \ldots, v_n$ and doesn't involve $v_1$ (because of the zeros in the first column). The induction will be to restrict $T$ to the subspace $\operatorname{span}\{v_2,\ldots, v_n\}$ (so, the restriction of $T$ is the matrix $N$) and to repeat the process. Any eigenvector of this restriction will be in the span of $v_2,\ldots,v_n$ and therefore be orthogonal to $v_1$ by assumption.

---

Edit 2:

> I don't understand why $T(c_2 v_2 + \cdots + c_n v_n)$ does not involve $v_1$.

$T(c_2 v_2 + \cdots + c_n v_n)$ rewritten in the matrix representation is
$$
%M \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ c_2 \\ \vdots \\ c_n\end{bmatrix}=
\left[\begin{array}{c|ccc}a & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ \hline 0 \\ \vdots &&N\\0 \end{array}\right]
\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ c_2 \\ \vdots \\ c_n\end{bmatrix}.
$$
If you multiply the matrix with the vector, the first entry (the coefficient of $v_1$) will be zero.

> For example, take $v_2$, which is orthogonal to $v_1$. All we know of $M$ is that $m_{1j}=0$ for $j>1$ and $m_{i1}=0$ for $i>1$. How can we ever determine the unique image of $v_2$, unless $M$ is a diagonal matrix?

The image of $v_2$ (that is, $T(v_2)$) can be rewritten in the matrix representation as
$$
M \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0\\ \vdots \\ 0\end{bmatrix}
%=\left[\begin{array}{c|ccc}a & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ \hline 0 \\ \vdots &&N\\0 \end{array}\right]
%\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The resulting vector contains the coefficients for $T(v_2)$ as a linear combination of $v_1, \ldots, v_n$. It is unique because $v_1, \ldots, v_n$ is a basis.

> How do we know that the <s>eigenvalue</s> eigenvector of $N$ (and hence that of $M$ <s>with a zero added at the $m_{12}$ position</s> after appending a zero at the front of the eigenvector) can be expressed as the linear sum of $v_2,\ldots,v_n$?

We are now looking at the subspace $\operatorname{span}\{v_2, \ldots, v_n\}$ (i.e., vectors of the form $(0,c_2,\ldots, c_n)^T$. We showed above that its image under $T$ also lies in this same subspace, so we can ignore the first coordinate entirely. So if $c_2 v_2 + \cdots+ c_n v_n$ is an eigenvector, i.e., $T(c_2 v_2 + \cdots +c_n v_n)=\lambda (c_2 v_2 + \cdots +c_n v_n)$, then $T(0 v_1 + c_2 v_2 + \cdots +c_n v_n)=\lambda (0 v_1 + c_2 v_2 + \cdots +c_n v_n)$. Or in matrix form,
$$
N \begin{bmatrix} c_2 \\ \vdots \\ c_n\end{bmatrix}
= \lambda \begin{bmatrix} c_2 \\ \vdots \\ c_n\end{bmatrix}
\implies
\left[\begin{array}{c|ccc}a & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ \hline 0 \\ \vdots &&N\\0 \end{array}\right]
\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ c_2 \\ \vdots \\ c_n\end{bmatrix}
= \lambda \begin{bmatrix} 0\\ c_2 \\ \vdots \\ c_n\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Comment: Could you substantiate that? I was thinking along the same lines, but I don't quite know how to prove that.

Comment: Just confirming. $(a,0,0,0\dots,0)^t$ is not $v_1$, is it?

Comment: @AyushKhaitan No, that is not $v_1$. My answer might have been misleading, I am fixing it.

Comment: I don't understand why $T(c_2v_2+\dots c_nv_n)$ does not involve $v_1$. For example, take $v_2$, which is orthogonal to $v_1$. All we know of $M$ is that $m_{1j}=0$ for $j>1$ and $m_{i1}=0$ for $i>1$. How can we ever determine the **unique** image of $v_2$, unless $M$ is a diagonal matrix?

Comment: How do we know that the eigenvalue of $N$ (and hence that of $M$ with a zero added at the $m_{12}$ position) can be expressed as the linear sum of $v_2,\dots,v_n$?

Comment: @AyushKhaitan see my edits above